# Laravel 4 ReflectionException on DI

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-4

I am working on a code as a new developer and after long refactoring I got one error that is bugging me. One method id erroring out, and it is throwing a `ReflectionException: Class does not exist`. The error is thrown in this line:

```
$shippingService = App::make('ShippingServiceInterface');
```

The actual class does of course exist. I've tried running `composer dump-autoload`, and halting and bringing up vagrant machine up again but no avail.

Interface itself has two methods and is namespaced.

Folder structure is different than regular Laravel app in a way that everything is stored in a `lib` folder which is autoloaded completely through `composer.json`.

Any ideas how can I track this issue down?

EDIT:

I tried adding it to an existing service provider and then running `dump-autoload`, but still the same.

EDIT 2:

Even stranger thing is that in `autoload_classmap.php` I see the class being loaded after running `dump-autoload`

Comment: Have you bound a class to `ShippingServiceInterface` in a service provider?

Comment: Well that was my first clue since everything else is actually in a provider...but when switching to old branch, function works without that one being in the service provider

Comment: I'm not sure how it would, if nothing is bound, then how can Laravel possibly know what you want?

Comment: Well...it is awesome? :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the error being actually that the interface which was injected didn't have any object which implemented it, thus no concrete class could actually be injected.